# Getting these error when trying to test component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test some components but I'm not being able to.
It's throwing me an error on `mount()` and `shallow()`:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

I'm using `react-router-dom` for routing.

Here's all the components.

render-component.jsx (highest component):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HeaderSection from './header-section';
import BodySection from './body-section';
import FooterSection from './footer-section';
import Footer from '../footer';
import NavBar from '../nav-bar';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class RenderComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        showLogin: false
    }

    getHomeFooterName = () => {
        if (this.props.location.pathname === '/') return 'our-footer';
        return 'footeri'
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <NavBar />
                {this.props.children.find(component => component.type === HeaderSection)}
                <section className="content">
                    {this.props.children.find(component => component.type === BodySection)}
                </section>
                <section name={this.getHomeFooterName()} id="footer" >
                    {this.props.children.find(component => component.type === FooterSection)}
                    <Footer />
                </section>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(RenderComponent);
```

header-section.jsx, body-section.jsx and footer-section.jsx are the same, they just render childrens:

```
import React from 'react';

const BodySection = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {children}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default BodySection;
```

Here's my home.jsx where I call these components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CoreValues from './core-values';
import History from './history'
import News from './news';
import Subscribe from './subscribe';
import HeaderSection from '../sections/header-section';
import BodySection from '../sections/body-section';
import FooterSection from '../sections/footer-section';
import RenderComponent from '../sections/render-component';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Home extends Component {
    state = {};

    goToElement = props => {
        //some us of this.props.location and this.props.history
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <RenderComponent isHomePage={true}>
                <HeaderSection>
                    <MetaTags>
                        <title>Super Viva</title>
                    </MetaTags>
                </HeaderSection>

                <BodySection>
                    <CoreValues />
                    <History />
                    <News />
                </BodySection>

                <FooterSection>
                    <Subscribe />
                </FooterSection>
            </RenderComponent>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

And I'm trying to test that this home.jsx renders successfully `CoreValues, History, News, Subscribe` and even `RenderComponent, HeaderSection, BodySection and FooterSection`, and some other childs inside.

Below you have my `home.test.js` with all the options I tried to test if its rendering `Header`. Just so you know, I'm using `home.find().dive()`, because I need them to render so I don't have to write tests for all of them explicitly in order to make code-coverage.

I did also use that `react-router-test-context` but it doesnt seems to work.

home.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import createRouterContext from 'react-router-test-context';
import Home from './home';
import Header from './header';
import { BrowserRouter, MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
const context = createRouterContext();

describe('<Home />', () => {
    it('should render <Header />', async () => {
        const home = shallow(<Home />, { context });
        expect(home.find(Header).dive()).toHaveLength(1); //Method “dive” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
    });

    it('should render <Header /> 1', async () => {
        const home = mount(<Home />, { context }); //Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
        expect(home.find(Header).dive()).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it('should render <Header /> 2', async () => {
        const home = shallow(<BrowserRouter><Home /></BrowserRouter>);
        expect(home.find(Header).dive()).toHaveLength(1); //Method “dive” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
    });

    it('should render <Header /> 3', async () => {
        const home = shallow(<MemoryRouter><Home /></MemoryRouter>);
        expect(home.find(Header).dive()).toHaveLength(1); //Method “dive” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
    });
})
```

Here are all error I get:

> Method “dive” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead
>
> Invariant Violation: You should not use  or withRouter() outside a

while in another test file where Component its not wrapper with `withRouter(Component)` like `withRouter(Home)`, i get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Shallow mounting does not render a components children (Header, Body, Footer in your case). It's only going to render 'RenderComponent'. Have you tried using mount and wrapping it with BrowserRouter?

Basically like your third test example ('should render  2'), but use mount instead.

Comment: Yes that `mount()` wrapping with BrowserRouter its throwing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

To test a component that contains `withRouter`, you can simply use `WrappedComponent` to get the component wrapped with `withRouter`

```
const Wrapper = shallow(<UserComponent.WrappedComponent />)
```

You could refer [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter/componentwrappedcomponent) docs for clear info